# Organizing Nested Object Data in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

**Question:**

How do I organize the "Inventory Object Data" shown in the example below, so that it is more usable like the desired example "Result" shown below?

*ES6 Methods Only.*

**Example Data:**

```js
const data = [
  { number: 1, desc: "I1", location: "L1", stock: 20 },
  { number: 2, desc: "I2", location: "L2", stock: 80 },
  { number: 3, desc: "I3", location: "L3", stock: 400 },
  { number: 1, desc: "I1", location: "L5", stock: 203 },
  { number: 1, desc: "I1", location: "L4", stock: 255 },
  { number: 2, desc: "I2", location: "L6", stock: 80 },
  { number: 2, desc: "I2", location: "L3", stock: 70 },
  { number: 3, desc: "I3", location: "L1", stock: 90 }
];
```

**Desired Result:**

```js
const organizedList = {
  listName: "L1",
  items: [
    {
      number: 1,
      item: "I1",
      locations: [
        { loc: "L1", stock: 20 },
        { loc: "L5", stock: 203 },
        { loc: "L4", stock: 255 }
      ]
    },
    {
      number: 2,
      item: "I2",
      locations: [
        { loc: "L2", stock: 80 },
        { loc: "L6", stock: 80 },
        { loc: "L3", stock: 70 }
      ]
    },
    {
      number: 3,
      item: "I3",
      locations: [
        { loc: "L3", stock: 400 },
        { loc: "L1", stock: 90 }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

**Result Description:**

Each individual item is now in a single object within the list while each item also has its own respective locations and counts within its own object array.

**My Approach:**

```js
const dataNumbers = data.map((item) => {
  return item.number;
});

const uniqueNumbers = [...new Set(dataNumbers)];

console.log(uniqueNumbers);

function getAllIndexes(arr, val) {
  var indexes = [],
    i = -1;
  while ((i = arr.indexOf(val, i + 1)) != -1) {
    indexes.push(i);
  }
  return indexes;
}

const items = [];

const list = {
  listName: "test",
  items: items
};

for (let i = 0; i < uniqueNumbers.length; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  const indexes = getAllIndexes(dataNumbers, uniqueNumbers[i]);
  const indexedItem = data.filter((items) => {
    return items.number === uniqueNumbers[i];
  });

  const locations = indexedItem.map((item) => {
    const loc = item.location;
    const stock = item.stock;
    return { loc, stock };
  });
  const item = {
    number: uniqueNumbers[i],
    locations: locations
  };
  items.push(item);
}
console.log(list);
```

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-zhukovsky-xogp6?file=/src/index.js

I know it's a tall order, but any tips on shortening this code would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution where we iterate the data and use findIndex to see if there is item desc. If index is found we push new location else we create new item.

```
let items = []

data.forEach(item =>{
    let index = items.findIndex(i => i.number===item.number)
    if(index>=0){
        items[index].locations.push({
            loc:item.location,
            stock:item.stock
        })
    }else{
        items.push({
            number:item.number,
            item:item.desc,
            locations:[{
                loc:item.location,
                stock:item.stock
            }]
        })
    }
})

const organizedList = {
    listName: "L1",
    items:items
}

console.log(organizedList)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Much shorter than my attempt. I'll take a look through this and hopefully learn something new!

Comment: I like your approach because It was simple and I understood it, but correct me if I'm wrong. First, it loops through the data and pushes all of the unique items first listed data into the variable. Then when the findIndex function sees a repeating number, it then pushes in the next location keys and values until there are no more occurrences?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution could be a reduce function such as:

```
function organize (result, item, index, array) {
  if (!result.items) result.items = []
  if (!result.items[item.number]) {
    result.items[item.number] = {
      number: item.number,
      item: item.desc,
      locations: []
    }
  }
  result.items[item.number].locations.push({
    loc: item.location,
    stock: item.stock
  })
  if (array.length === index + 1) {
    result.items = Object.keys(result.items).map(i => result.items[i])
  }
  return result
}
```

Usage:

```
const myList = data.reduce(organize, { listName: 'L1' })
```

Notes:

- `data` object is the example data list from the question;
- above form allows for extending resulting object with additional information depending on what is passed as initial data to `reduce(callback, initialValue)` function.
- more information on reduce https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Thank you, much shorter than my example, ill upvote this when I'm back to lvl 15!